# Angular refresh access token on isAuthenticated call

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to set up `jwt` authentication with `refresh token`. I have this method in my `authenticationService`:

```js
isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  return !jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getAccessToken());
}
```

And I want to use it like this:

```js
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
  const jwtHelper = new JwtHelperService();
  if (!jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.getAccessToken())) {
    return of(true);
  }
  return this.refreshToken(); // returns Observable<boolean>
}
```

So, I want always to have valid access token instead of refreshing it on each api call (which is probably better) because I use it in `*ngIf` to not show some component if user is not logged in. So, how to do a one call to `refreshToken` for all calls to `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: The above code should work. All you need to use an `async` pipe combined with `*ngIf` since it returns an observable.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I want to use `async` pipe but if I have multiple `*ngIf` it will cause a lot of `refreshToken` calls. So, I'm asking how to avoid this multiple calls. And I want to solve it on the service side, not the component, so`isAuthenticated` can be used in other services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to use flow from this [post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/25/angular-10-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens). I added `app initialzer` (which call `refreshToken`) and replaced `isAuthenticated` with

```
isAuthenticated(): boolean {
  return this.gerUserData() != null;
}
```

I think this flow is better because refreshing token every time when it's expired is useless without api calls with payload.